# Is there a better way to say "closer to the wee hours of the morning"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there a better way to say "closer to the wee hours of the morning"?

> If you sleep closer to the wee hours of the morning (like 5:00 AM
> instead of 11:00 PM or 12:00PM or 1:00 AM), you will have a harder
> time waking up.

I can't think of a better way to put it. Is there a better and shorter phrase?

Comment: Saying that something is 'wee' is idiomatic only in Scotland. Elsewhere it is the 'small hours'.

Comment: They have wee things including small hours, and famously, [donkeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7oa3kPQJKo) in Northern Ireland, so they do!

Comment: The sequence "closer to the wee hours" (or "...small hours") isn't very idiomatic. Perhaps consider *If you go to bed nearer to the time you get up...* It's all basically Off Topic writing advice, but *my* advice would be not to bother with so many explicit statements of the obvious - just *If you go to bed **much later...***

Comment: Do you mean 'if you don't _go to sleep until_ the wee/small hours'? Most people sleep through those hours.

Comment: @WeatherVane In the UK that may be true, but in America it's just an idiom. One that's often used without any conscious understanding that "wee" is supposed to mean "low in number", at that.

Comment: Most people who go to sleep by midnight also sleep at 5am.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, the word 'wee' meaning small is thought of as being particular to Scottish and Irish dialects, although it isn't unusual for those from England to use it as a borrowed word. However, "*the wee hours*" is an idiomatic expression. I've heard it used by Americans, and I was once asked by a Filipino what it meant as they had encountered it in English literature. It seems to be pretty widely known, if not widely used.

'The wee hours' literally means '*the small hours*' and generally refers to the earliest hours of the morning (eg 1am, 2am, 3am etc). As an Englishman, I would simply say "*the early hours of the morning*". As many people idiomatically call the hours that they would normally be asleep as "night time", it wouldn't be unusual for someone to say that a time like 1am was "the middle of the night", even though any time after midnight is technically the morning.

I'm not sure what you are trying to say, as times like 5am, 6am etc may be unsociably early for some, but not for others. Some people rise for work between 5am and 6am; others maybe not until 7am or later. I would not call 5am "the wee hours".

Are you not simply trying to say "the longer you sleep, the harder it is to wake up" ?

Comment: I think OP is more saying the later you fall asleep, the harder it is to get up in the morning (assuming you're waking up at the same time regardless). But +1 for the rest.

Comment: @cjl750 Maybe that's what they meant. But to sleep **to** a time means to sleep *until* that time, so they actually said the complete opposite of what you suggest. Got to take it at face value. You've got to be able to speak English well enough to construct a question in order to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP meant to say

> If you *fall asleep* in the ***very*
> early** hours of the morning, you'll find it harder to get up for school/work.

to *fall asleep* is the same as someone *going to sleep*, *asleep* is an adjective.

To wake up at 5am is pretty normal for millions of people across the world, anyone who goes to sleep around 5am but has to wake up between 7am and 9am will probably not hear the alarm ring and oversleep.